# Dragging a dock panel from one host window to another?

Tags: dockpanel, dockpanel-suite

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to configure DockPanelSuite to allow dragging of docked windows from one dock container window to another?  The demo application shows the menu option Window --> New Window, which creates a new dock container window, but dockable windows cannot be dragged between the two (for example to support multiple monitors with a dock container window on each screen).

Comment: Sorry to hinder your karma-whoring with an original question?

Comment: As maintainers we have to monitor various sources for new questions and of course mark duplicates to save efforts, https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/wiki/KB100003 Thus, personally I hope less users choose to post duplicate things to multiple locations.